# jquery .on parent selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

There used to be:

```
$("#element").parent().click(function() { alert("smth"); });
```

What's the equivalent of this with new jQuery event delegation `on` ?

```
$(document).on("click", "how to select #element parent here?", function() { alert("smth"); });
```

UPDATE:
Actual code (although I don't see what this could change)

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ":has(>.hoverPhone)", function() {
    alert("smth");
});
```

"#hoverPhone" is a span in cells of one of the columns of jquery data table.

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class=" sorting_1">05/11/2012</td>
    <td class="">Surname</td>
    <td class="">
        <span class="hoverPhone" title="Alternative No: 0123456789">9876543210</span>
    </td>
    <td class="">DIGITAL CAMERA</td>
    <td class="">6140</td>
    <td class="">CAMTRONICS</td>
    <td class="">clarify</td>
</tr>
```

This still doesn't work by the way.

UPDATE 2: Seems to be working. Personal comment, however... ":has(>.element)" really, jQuery? What's next? This is getting more and more confusing.

Comment: Make a fiddle for us showing what you're doing exactly. This will help formulate better answers.

Comment: Regarding your comment in update 2 : jquery has to deal both with some kind of compatibility with css (which was incrementally built) and with many complex cases. That's not easy. You'll be more chocked the day you'll go deep in regex...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest I have :

```
$(document).on("click", ":has(>#element)", function(){...
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/QTwTg/)

Comment: Though `"> elem"` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) for some reason, this is the only short approach I see.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why it's being deprecated as it seems so much more selective than the general descendant selector.

Comment: @dystroy As well as I'd pay my 1€ to those who can prove me that `:text` selector should be also [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/). The stupidest decision ever.

Comment: I hadn't see this one. I'm not intimate enough with the development of jQuery to be sure it's stupid but it looks so...

Comment: @VisioN: Apparently, `:text` is deprecated because it's just* syntactic sugar for `[type=text]`, and being as it is, it is not warranted to keep it, when it comes with the drawback of not being able to optimize into `querySelectorAll`. Although having said that I can't see why they can't hack that optimization manually. (* sort of)

Comment: @DavidHedlund `<input>` element will also have type `text` by default, but you can't select it with `[type=text]`. Meanwhile, `:text` successfully did this job.

Comment: @DavidHedlund it's syntaxic sugar as long as you don't leave (as I always do) the type unspecified because it defaults to "text".

Comment: @VisioN: yeah, that was what I had in mind when I added the *, above. It is a minor difference, but I am inclined to believe this is the reason it's deprecated anyway.

Comment: @DavidHedlund That's not minor actually. I would agree with the deprecation if both methods do the same job, like `:first` and `:eq(0)`. However, they behave differently and I see no reason for deprecation. Slower is not the answer here, while `[type=text]` is not a silver bullet.

Comment: @Caballero you confuse class and id. Test with `id=hoverPhone` in your element or change the selector to `":has(>.hoverPhone)"`.

Comment: @dystroy Sorry about that, I've changed it to dot, still doesn't work though.

Comment: Cool. For everybody, here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/q6UAE/) with OP's HTML (I was trying to guess the error).

Answer (score 2):

You can still assign event listeners in the same manner:

```
$('#element').parent().on('click', function() { });
```

Comment: He's looking to use delegation though.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what's being requested.

Comment: @Caballero: It's not supposed to work if you want dynamic delegation. It's just the `.on` equivalent of your `.click` and to that extent it works ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka8jP/)).

Answer (score 1):

This would still work fine:

```
$("#element").parent().on("click", function() {
     alert("smth"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for delegation to handle dynamically added elements then you can't do it the way you propose.  You need to handle the click event for all elements that *could* be the parent and check if they have the element in question as a child...

```
$(document).on("click", "*", function() {
    if ($(this).children("#element").length > 0) {
        alert("parent clicked");
    }
});
```

I'd strongly recommend changing `document` to a closer container element, and change `*` to the parent tag type, if possible.